# Exporting issue with colours in AutoCAD Civil 3D

Tags: export, printing, autocad

I hope someone can tell me what's going on here.  On the left is what the image looks like in CAD and on the right is the result when I export to pdf format.  I also get the same color results when I send it to the printer.  As you can see, none of my other hatch patterns are giving me this issue besides the black area under "YOU ARE HERE".

Suggestions?  Thanks in advance.[image]

**ADDITION TO ORIGINAL QUESTION**  I managed to achieve the appearance of the image on the left by adjusting the RGB value of the layer (very slightly).  The .pdf export and print both worked.  I changed one of the numeric settings such that the colour was not set to "absolute" black and it worked.  I would still like to know the answer to the original question though.  Although I've found a work-around, I still want to know why black does not print accordingly.